# App crashes when I try to read data from Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Kotlin, and I was trying to insert and read data from Cloud Firestore with the following code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val insertButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.insertButton)
        val getButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.getButton)

        insertButton.setOnClickListener {
            db.collection("users").document("testUser").set(
                hashMapOf("name" to "test1", "username" to "test2")
            )
        }

        getButton.setOnClickListener {
            db.collection("users").document("testUser").get().addOnSuccessListener {
                findViewById<EditText>(R.id.test1TextView).setText(it.get("name") as String)
                findViewById<EditText>(R.id.test2TextView).setText(it.get("username") as         
                String)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Layout file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test1TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test2TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/insertButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="insert" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get" />
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The app is simple, with two buttons, one to insert on the database and the other to read from it and change some TextViews with the read data. The app looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VLXG.png

The "Insert" button works fine and creates the data on the Firestore properly (Firestore image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/anapG.png). The problem comes when  the "Get" button is clicked and the app tries to read data from the Firestore, it simply crashes.

Logcat output:

```
--------- beginning of crash
2022-03-15 06:04:15.889 20433-20433/com.eugenisb.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.eugenisb.testapp, PID: 20433
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
    at com.eugenisb.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-2$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:28)
    at com.eugenisb.testapp.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$dpktUtUdZqv_kK0jh4DAEzfEDP0(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.eugenisb.testapp.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onSuccess(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I do not know if the solution to this is trivial, but I tried searching for a solution to this and did not find it.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: If the app crashes it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat output. Please find those and edit your question to include them.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your layout file. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the layout file to the question. The accepted answer worked and now it does not crash anymore, but thank you anyway for your interest and comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the crash logs you're using MaterialTextView rather than EditTextView. Change the type cast of `findViewById<EditText>(R.id.test1TextView).setText(it.get("name") as String)` to `findViewById<MaterialTextView >(R.id.test1TextView).setText(it.get("name") as String)` or what ever type of textview you are using. Perhaps show your xml layout to further confirm the type of view you are using.

Comment: Yes, changing the cast worked. As you said, I was trying to change the text of an EditText when it was a TextView. That was what made it crash, now works properly. Thank you!!